# Single Update and Delete API for two models connected with a OneToOne relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I've looked extensively on here and probably exhausted all the answers and still haven't found a solution to my particular problem, which is to make an API that update/delete from both models, and I am getting the following error:

`The` .update()`method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit`.update()`method for serializer`user_profile.serializers.UserSerializer`, or set` read_only=True `on nested serializer fields.`

In this particular instance this happens when I try to update a field from the **user_profile** model

I have separated my Django project into several apps/folders with each model being in its own folder.

I have a **user** app and a **user_profile** app each with their own models.

the user model is basically an AbstractUser sitting in its own app

the **user_profile** model is as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(to=User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='userprofile')
    location = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=30)
    created_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

The serializers are as follows:

```
class UserProfileCrudSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('location', 'created_time', 'updated_time')


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileCrudSerializer(source='userprofile', many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')

        def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            userprofile_serializer = self.fields['profile']
            userprofile_instance = instance.userprofile
            userprofile_data = validated_data.pop('userprofile', {})

            userprofile_serializer.update(userprofile_instance, userprofile_data)

            instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
            return instance
```

and my view is:

```
class RetrieveUpdateView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

when I do a GET I am getting the following response without any problems:

```
{
    "username": "blue",
    "email": "bluebear@bluebear.com",
    "first_name": "Blue",
    "last_name": "Bear",
    "profile": {
        "location": "London",
        "created_time": "2023-02-03T00:39:15.149924Z",
        "updated_time": "2023-02-03T00:39:15.149924Z"
    }
}
```

and I do a patch request like this:

```
{
    "profile": {
        "location": "Paris"
    }
}
```

The way the code is now I have no issue updating username, email, first_name, and last_name which come from the AbstractUser but I am getting the above error when I try to patch the location which is in the UserProfile model.

I've looked at many similar solutions online, but none that pertain to my particular situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The .update() method does not support writable nested fields by default. Write an explicit .update() method for serializeruser_profile.serializers.UserSerializer, or set read_only=True on nested serializer fields.

It already shows in the message, you need to explicitly write the update method for the writable nested serializer which is documented here https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/writable-nested-serializers/ or you can use another module that is also referred to in the docs https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested.

Your approach is correct already but there is some typo and wrong indentation in your code:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    profile = UserProfileCrudSerializer(source='userprofile', many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'profile')

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # update is a method of serializer not serializer.Meta
        userprofile_serializer = self.fields['profile']
        userprofile_instance = instance.userprofile
        # should be 'profile' here instead of 'userprofile' as you defined in serializer
        userprofile_data = validated_data.pop('profile', {})

        userprofile_serializer.update(userprofile_instance, userprofile_data)

        instance = super().update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```